# Unable to add files and commit in Jgit

Tags: git, egit, jgit

I have manually made changes on the test repository. Also, I have verified it using git status from cmd line. I am trying to commit this change programmatically using jgit. When I execute the below code, the commit happens successfully. However, the changes which I made is not reflecting. It's just an empty commit without any changes. Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

```
public static void commit(Git target) {
    try {
         target.add().addFilepattern("*.*").call();
         target.commit().setMessage("test commit").call();
    } catch (GitAPIException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [`AddCommand.addFilepattern()`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/AddCommand.html#addFilepattern(java.lang.String)) method docs:

> filepattern - File to add content from. Also a leading directory name (e.g. dir to add dir/file1 and dir/file2) can be given to add all files in the directory, recursively. Fileglobs (e.g. *.c) are not yet supported.

Which suggests that you should specify the path to the working directory e.g. `addFilepattern(".")`.